# Choosing the interface in multi-homed hosts

Tags: sockets, multihomed

When programming through sockets in C, one can automatically get information about their interfaces through the `getaddrinfo` function by invoking it with the node as `NULL` and the `AI_PASSIVE` flag in `hints.ai_flags`. It returns a list of `addrinfo` structures that will be suitable for `bind()`ing and `accept()`ing connections. On a multi-homed host with a default interface configured, `getaddrinfo` will return structures pertaining to the default interface which might not be the right one. How can `getaddrinfo` be invoked to return structures from all available interfaces so that the one can be chosen appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to set node as NULL. Set it to the IP address of the interface you want.

```
socket_result = getaddrinfo(NULL, port_num_string, &hints, &sock_addr_list);
```

to

```
socket_result = getaddrinfo("192.168.1.10", port_num_string, &hints, &sock_addr_list);
```

From the man page:

There are several reasons why the linked list may have more than one addrinfo structure,
including: the network host is multihomed, accessible over multiple protocols (e.g. both
AF_INET and AF_INET6); or the same service is available from multiple socket types  (one SOCK_STREAM  address and another SOCK_DGRAM address, for example).

Use getifaddr to search through all interfaces manually.